# Word insert Quick Part in IF THEN (serial letter)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am creating a Word serial letter from an Excel sheet.

Now I want to check if a field in Excel is empty. If so, output text. If it is **not** empty, output a quick part.

I already tried it several times, but I couldn't make it work.
Maybe it should look kinda like this:

```
{ IF RowXY = "" "No content in RowXY" { AUTOTEXT "Quickpart_Test" } }
```

I just need to know how to tell Word, it should output a predefined area, if a specific row is not empty. The quick part (autotext) also contains fields for the serial letter.

With researching I got no better solution approach than this one. My favorite way would be something like this:

```
{{ IF field == empty }}
     This text comes out
{{ ELSE }}
     Text nr. 2 comes out
{{ FINISH }}
```

Maybe I'm approaching it wrong. If so, is there a better solution?

Comment: How are you doing this? With VBA? A script? Excel? Word?

Comment: Excel with data, Word serial letter importing the Excel data. No VBA, no Scripts (yet). I'm looking for a solution, not matter what kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two AutoText entries - one for when your field is empty and the other for non-empty values. In this example I will call them `AutoTextWhenEmpty` and `AutoTextWhenHasValue` respectively.

Assuming your field is called `MyField` you can use the `MERGEFIELD` function to test its value and embed the correct AutoText entry in the resulting document.

Here's the formula:

`{ AUTOTEXT { if { MERGEFIELD MyField }="" "AutoTextWhenEmpty" "AutoTextWhenHasValue" } }`

You'll need to use `CTRL`+`F9` to insert the curly braces, you can't just type them. If you do it correctly the braces will appear bold. Here's a screenshot taken in Word 2010:

[image]